# Tooltip text using Selenium 2 + Java when tootip is a parameter in onmouseover method

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium

How can I get a tooltip for a link Footnote using Selenium 2 + Java? I am expecting "Tooltip for footnote" as the text.

html is as:

```
<a onmouseout="rdm.js.util.RDMUtils.hideTooltip(event);return true"
onmouseover="rdm.js.util.RDMUtils.showTooltipEncoded(event, 
"<p>;</p>; Tooltip for footnote <br />");return true"
href="#">Footnote</a>
```

Comment: format your post please

Answer (score 0):

this is a code that work form me

```
      WebElement element = findElement(driver, cssSelector, 1);
      Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
      actions.moveToElement(element);
      actions.perform();
      element.getText();
```

Comment: I got the solution :  we can use getAttribute to get the text from onmouseover method as shown below :                              String tooltip = driver.findElement(By.id("locator")).getAttribute("onmouseover");         Then use String compare() method to check if the tool tip text is present in the String extracted above